# updating property method by variables

Tags: javascript, oop

I wanna to change object's property via method called this code:

```
MAP = MAP || {
   level: 0
   updateProperty(property, value){
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(property){
          this.property = value
        }
   }
}
```

but when I fire this code I create new property named 'property' in my object. But I wanna treat 'property' as variable, not as new property!

Comment: Warning: epoch has declared your MAP object locally in his snippet. So if you hadn't noticed it I hope you won't spend another hour to figure out that your variable is not global anymore... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this (square brackets `this[property] = value;`)

```
var MAP = MAP || {};
MAP = {
    level: 0,
    updateProperty(property, value) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            this[property] = value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: woooow! thanks mate! I was working out this problem for last 1h! cheers! :)